# Как для каждого графика seaborn relplot установить значние y axis min, max при общем x-axis, а также отобразить percentile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

Как для каждого графика seaborn relplot установить индивидуальное значние y-axis min, max при общем x-axis, а также отобразить на каждом графике percentile (2.75, 50, 97.5) в виде красных горизонтальных линий?

Ниже приведен рабочий код, который нужно аддаптировать под требования.
Также приведены графики которые генерирует текущий код.
Код запускаю в Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 

sns.set()

ndf = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'mean', 'value': 20.0}, {'name': 'gmean', 'value': 5.885661912765424}, {'name': 'hmean', 'value': 29.240506329113924}, {'name': 'mean', 'value': 23.0}, {'name': 'gmean', 'value': 4.355877174692862}, {'name': 'hmean', 'value': 34.87096774193548}, {'name': 'mean', 'value': 15.2}, {'name': 'gmean', 'value': 4.949232003839765}, {'name': 'hmean', 'value': 22.13114754098361}, {'name': 'mean', 'value': 10.0}])
sns.relplot(data=ndf, x=ndf.index, y="value", hue="name", row="name")
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) Добавьте строки с инклудами, чтобы проще было ваш код воспроизводить. 2) Что вы уже пытались найти/сделать самостоятельно? Я ведь чтобы вам помочь буду точно так же гуглить примеры в интернете вообще и на английской версии Stackoverflow в частности. Там всё есть, нужно только найти и собрать вместе все нужные рецепты.

Comment: ваш код, кстати, нерабочий. у вас индекс длиной в 10 позиций. а графиков - 3

Comment: Я в https://seaborn.pydata.org/ смотрел и в гугле. Пока не нашел нужного ответа.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev Почитайте этот вопрос, может поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61725336/seaborn-relplot-subplots-axis-limit